# Is there any other way to fix an element in Vuetify other than v-toolbar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, position, fixed, vuetify.js

I've been trying to fix some elements in particular positions in the app. the only way that seems to work is something like this:

`<v-toolbar fixed></v-toolbar>`

or something like this:

`<v-toolbar app></v-toolbar>`.

Is there any other way to fix an element in Vuetify? Probably a Card or Layout or something?

`<v-card fixed> </v-card>` or `<v-layout row fixed> </v-layout>`

PS: (I know there are ways to do this by css but I want to know about Vuetify.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
style="position: fixed"
```